# How to prevent one click function to be called within two click function?

Tags: swift, macos, gesture

I am trying to add custom behaviour to my buttons. If clicked once - one action is performed. If clicked twice another one is performed.

I saw [such a solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274838/how-to-remove-pangesture-after-touch-in-swift) and I have tried all possible combinations:

```
        clickOnce.shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
        clickTwice.shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
        clickOnce.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
        clickTwice.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
        clickOnce.canPreventGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
        clickOnce.canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
        clickTwice.canPreventGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
        clickTwice.canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
```

But nothing worked for me.

And here's the full code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let buttonTestOne = NSButton(frame: CGRect(x: 500, y: 500, width: 100, height: 500))

        let clickOnceForTestOne = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: buttonTestOne, action: #selector(ViewController.clickOneTime(_:)))
        clickOnceForTestOne.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
        buttonTestOne.addGestureRecognizer(clickOnceForTestOne)
        self.view.addSubview(buttonTestOne)

        let arrTestButtons = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

        var x = 0
        var y = 0

        for item in arrTestButtons{
            let buttonNew = NSButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100))
            x = x + 120
            y = y + 120
            buttonNew.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: item)
            let clickOnce = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickOneTime(_:)))
            clickOnce.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
            buttonNew.addGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
            let clickTwice = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickTwoTimes(_:)))
            clickTwice.numberOfClicksRequired = 2
            buttonNew.addGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
            clickOnce.shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
            clickTwice.shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
            clickOnce.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
            clickTwice.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
            clickOnce.canPreventGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
            clickOnce.canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)
            clickTwice.canPreventGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)
            clickTwice.canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer(clickOnce)

            self.view.addSubview(buttonNew)
        }


    }

    func clickOneTime(g:NSClickGestureRecognizer){
        if g.state == .Ended {
            Swift.print("single click")
        }
    }
    func clickTwoTimes(g: NSClickGestureRecognizer){
        if g.state == .Ended {
            Swift.print("DOUBLE CLICK!")
        }
    }
    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think the mistake must be pretty simple, I am either calling from the wrong place, or somewhat like that, but I can't understand.

Here is the log file, which is the same for all combinations:

Clicked once:

```
single click
```

As expected

Clicked twice:

```
single click
DOUBLE CLICK!
```

Which starts both single and double click.

I have read the documentation. And I've tried all the combinations, because  couldn't find a solution.

I have also tried with the logs. So `Swift.print(clickOnce.shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer(clickTwice))` and one of these, but it gives me `false`.

Comment: You cannot simply mash all kinds of lines of cod together and expect the code to run as expected. Read the docs for each of the methods you call and try to figure out which gesture recognizer can influence the other in what way.

Comment: The example you referred to is for iOS, not OS X, so clicking twice with a mouse probably won't have the same effect as double tapping with a  finger on a device. Also "nothing worked for me" gives no indication of how it's not working, and you should explain that in your question.

Comment: @luk2302 I didn't mash them all, I've just tried all the combinations and posted code like that for the brevity

Comment: I doubt you tried all of them, there are 2^8, aka 256 combinations. Please take my advice and read the documentation.

Comment: @luk2302 I have read the documentation, OK I haven't tried all the 256 combos, but I've tried what seemed to be the most logical from the documentation. Each one-by-one and altogether. At least if there could be a combination to work it would appear.

Comment: Have you tried *only* `clickOnce.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)`?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, sure. It was actually the first option, which I tried. In the set of all which I've tried it is now third, though it was the first one to try. Here's how I have tried and tested it: `clickOnce.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickTwice)` and `Swift.print("TEST!!!!", clickOnce.shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(clickTwice))` And here's the log: `TEST!!!! false
TEST!!!! false
TEST!!!! false
single click
single click
DOUBLE CLICK!` The first three lines work when running through the loop, the last three, when clicking. So it puts false from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this myself; it turns out that the solution is relatively straightforward.

Use a gesture recogniser for the double-click (here, I've added them to the view, but the same principle should work for buttons)

```
let doubleClickRecognizer = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickTwice))
doubleClickRecognizer.numberOfClicksRequired = 2
self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(doubleClickRecognizer)
```

Add

```
@objc func clickTwice() {
    print("double click")
}
```

and then handle single clicks through

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    print("mouse down; once")
}
```

(or appropriate equivalent).

NSGestureRecognizer has

```
var delaysPrimaryMouseButtonEvents: Bool
```

which by default is set to true, so with this combination, it waits until the doubleClickRecognizer has handled the double-click before going up the responder chain to see who else is interested in a mouseclick.

Two gesture recognisers have the same problem as handling single and double clicks in mouseDown: the single click fires first. In order to overcome this, you need to override

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

This is not a function you call, it's a delegate function that you override. So you set your viewController to conform to NSGestureRecognizerDelegate (which means it will receive delegate methods); set singleClickRecognizer.delegate = self (where self is your viewController), and implement

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == singleClickRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == doubleClickRecognizer {
        return true
    }
    return false
    }
```

which states that your singleClickRecognizer waits for the doubleClickRecognizer to fail before executing its selector.

Unfortunately, I have found that in SpriteKit, while this code does what it says on the tin (process a double-click first), it leads to unacceptable delays, so I'm not sure I can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let click = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clicked(_:))
click.numberOfClicksRequired = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try it this way, where "button" is your button

```
let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickTwoTimes(_:)))
let singleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickOneTime(_:)))
singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
button.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
button.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer)
singleTapRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTapRecognizer)
```

Comment: This is iOS and I am trying to find the solution for OS X.